# using output object from azure pipelines task in another task

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have the following two tasks in my project.  What I need to do is grab a value out of the configmap and use it as a parameter in the second call.

```
- task: Kubernetes@1
  name: msiguid
  displayName: Retrieve the MSI guid
  continueOnError: false
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceEndpoint: '${{ parameters.Environment }} AKS'
    command: get
    arguments: cm identity-configmap --namespace ${{ parameters.ProjectName }}
- task: HelmDeploy@0
  displayName: 'Helm Install'
  inputs:
    connectionType: 'Kubernetes Service Connection'
    kubernetesServiceConnection: '${{ parameters.Environment }} AKS'
    namespace: '${{ parameters.ProjectName }}'
    command: 'upgrade'
    chartType: 'FilePath'
    chartPath: '${{ parameters.LocalCheckedOutPath }}/${{ parameters.Path_To_Helm }}/${{ parameters.ProjectName }}'
    releaseName: '${{ parameters.ProjectName }}'
    overrideValues: |
      '${{ parameters.Helm_Install_Chart_Name }}.image.tag=$(SEMVER)' 
      '${{ parameters.Helm_Install_Chart_Name }}.userMsiGuid=$( msiguid.KubectlOutput.data.MANAGED_IDENTITY_APP_ID )
      '${{ parameters.Helm_Install_Chart_Name }}.keyvaultName=${{ parameters.KeyVaultName[parameters.Environment] }}'
    valueFile: '${{ parameters.LocalCheckedOutPath }}/${{ parameters.Path_To_Helm }}/${{ parameters.ProjectName }}/values-${{ parameters.Environment }}${{ parameters.Helm_Values_Subfile }}'
    install: true
    waitForExecution: false
```

The first task is successfully grabbing the config map and putting it in the internal variable and if i put in an `echo` task i can see it is filled with the entire configmap object.

Ive gone over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks over and over and i don't see why

`$( msiguid.KubectlOutput.data.MANAGED_IDENTITY_APP_ID )`

doesnt work seeing they are both tasks under the same job.  I should be able to reference the var like that.  Anyone have any ideas why

Comment: Did you try the bash way of setting variables.
######
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=cm;isOutput=true]$cm"

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can try to use the variable in the same job

```
  - bash: |
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myJobVar]this is the same job"
```

For more information, you could refer to [Set an output variable for use in the same job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-the-same-job).